# Is it possible to have two floats which fail lt, gt, and eq tests

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a block of code that looks something like this:

```
if a > b:
    pass
elif a < b:
    pass
elif a == b:
    pass
else:
    # Can I assume that a or b is nan if I'm here?
```

I want to know if reaching the final else block necessarily implies that either a or b is nan. Is there any other way to have two floats that fail the first three comparisons?

Comment: I believe so. `Inf == Inf`, and `-Inf == -Inf`; and those are the only  weird floats that I know of besides `NaN`.

Comment: Also negative and positive zero are equal to each other.

Comment: The math module also includes the `isnan` function for you to test explicitly.

Comment: The other key point here is that Python's floating-point operations always force the result of the underlying C operation into memory, so we avoid the unpredictabilities associated with extra intermediate precision and unpredictable x87 'register spill' that are present in some C environments.  (That still doesn't make Python immune from double-rounding problems, but that's not relevant for this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE 754 standard says:

> **5.7. Comparison**
>   It shall be possible to compare floating-point numbers in all supported
>   formats, even if the operands' formats differ. Comparisons are exact and
>   never overflow nor underflow. Four mutually exclusive relations are
>   possible: less than, equal, greater than, and unordered. The last case arises
>   when at least one operand is NaN. Every NaN shall compare unordered with
>   everything, including itself.

It means that if any or both comparison operands are NaNs - result os **>**, **<**, **==** will be false.

Since Python adheres to IEE754 standard you can safely assume that if at least one of your operands to (<,>,==) is **NaN** you'll end up in else statement.

You can verify that of course:

```
import math

nan = float("nan")

a_and_b = [ (1.0, 3.0), (3.0, nan), (nan, 3.0), (nan, nan)]

for (a,b) in a_and_b:
    print("a={} b={}".format(a,b))
    if a > b:
        print(' a>b')
    elif a < b:
        print(' a<b')
    elif a == b:
        print(' a==b')
    else:
        print(' else')
```

yields:

```
a=1.0 b=3.0
 a<b
a=3.0 b=nan
 else
a=nan b=3.0
 else
a=nan b=nan
 else
```

Since most of PCs have x87 FPU all floating point comparisons are accomplished by FCOM-like coprocessor instruction which results in setting 4 bits (C0..C3) is comprocessor's status word depending on result. Documentation excerpt:

[image]

On low level - after comparing 2 floats your program fetches FPU's status word and based on these 3 of 4 status flags decides what to do. Since at least one of your comparison arguments will be NaN you'll end up in the last case (**unordered**) and as I've already mentioned none of (>, <, ==) will return true hence you end up in your **else** statement